# Make [bcl] a synonym of [base-class-library]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[bcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bcl) has 112 questions and [base-class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-class-library) only has 17 questions, but we also use [portable-class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-class-library), so I suggest that we use the longer tag and make the acronym a synonym.